# Filter Pandas dataset by last occurrence of a value in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like this:

```
    Fruit    Qty
0   Apple    1
1   Orange   3
2   Pear     7
3   Orange   1
4   Pear     23
5   Lemon    5
```

And I'm trying to obtain this:

```
    Fruit    Qty
0   Apple    1
1   Orange   1
2   Pear     23
3   Lemon    5
```

So I would like to filter the rows of my dataset by the last of occurrence in 'Fruit' column.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `drop_duplicates`

```
s=df.drop_duplicates('Fruit',keep='last')


s
    Fruit  Qty
0   Apple    1
3  Orange    1
4    Pear   23
5   Lemon    5
```

Comment: No I'm not looking for this. For 'Orange' I need 3.